# Getting error: SqlException (0x80131904):Subquery returned more than 1 value - why?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Error when running my query :

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

This is my code:

```
UPDATE Trade
SET Reference = (SELECT DISTINCT temp.MainRecordNo
                 FROM temp
                 WHERE temp.SubRecordNo = Trade.TradeNo 
                   AND temp.LinkType = 'ATPD'
                   AND LinkStatus = 'A'
                   AND ISNULL(Trade.Reference, '') <> Temp.MainRecordNo)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT Temp.MainRecordNo
              FROM Temp
              WHERE Temp.SubRecordNo = Trade.TradeNo
                AND Temp.LinkType = 'ATPD'
                AND LinkStatus = 'A'
                AND ISNULL(Trade.CstpReference, '') <> Temp.MainRecordNo)
```

How to fix it?

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here; what about the error don't you understand and we can try to elaborate.

Comment: `set Reference = ` expects just one value, you cannot add more than one value in the column of one row. But your subquery returns more than one row, so you are trying to add more than one value into 1 row. The error is pretty clear about that

Comment: forget about your update statement, first create a list of records `one to one` relationship, you want to update.

Comment: want to select max number in MainRecordNo and what to update it

Answer (score 1):

First, you should rephrase this using a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE t
    set Reference = temp.MainRecordNo
FROM Trade t JOIN
     temp
     ON Temp.SubRecordNo = t.TradeNo
WHERE temp.LinkType = 'ATPD' AND
      temp.LinkStatus = 'A' AND  -- Guessing this comes from temp
      (t.CstpReference IS NULL OR t.CstpReference <> Temp.MainRecordNo);
```

This will solve your immediate problem.  You have another problem, which is that multiple records in `temp` match a single record in `Trade`.  It is entirely unclear how to resolve that.  This will update with a value from an arbitrary matching row.

Comment: From me challenge is multiple records in temp table match a single record in Trade

Comment: @NaveenB . . . Your question doesn't specify what to do.  I would suggest that you ask a new question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic.

Comment: multiple records in temp table(get max value) and match a single record in Trade

Answer (score 0):

Just for your ans try this, select `top 1` in `update` query when you are not sure about the number of `rows` return by your `subquery` :-

```
    Update Trade
    set Reference = (Select top 1 distinct temp.MainRecordNo
                        from temp
                        where temp.SubRecordNo = Trade.TradeNo 
                        and temp.LinkType = 'ATPD'
                        and LinkStatus = 'A'
                        and isnull(Trade.Reference,'') <> Temp.MainRecordNo)
    WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT DISTINCT Temp.MainRecordNo
        FROM Temp
        where Temp.SubRecordNo = Trade.TradeNo
        and Temp.LinkType = 'ATPD'
        and LinkStatus = 'A'
        and isnull(Trade.CstpReference,'') <> Temp.MainRecordNo)
```

Comment: Using `TOP 1` **without** an `ORDER BY` is typically quite useless - after all, which "top" rows will you get?? If you don't have an  `ORDER BY` clause, it's arbitrary.....

Comment: this will add a random value from the result set to his column. At least explain that to him

Comment: From me challenge is multiple records in temp table match a single record in Trade

Comment: How can i but order by to above query to solve this ?

Comment: here you need to figure out that from multiple records exactly which record do you want to insert.

Comment: want to select max number in MainRecordNo and what to update it

Comment: can you post some input and output sample